# Whats wrong with my code (GML)

Tags: gml

ok so im sorry to be asking, however im trying to make it so that when i press z, a portal appears at my Spr_players coordinates, however if one of them already exists, i want it to be erased and im simply wondering what ive done wrong. Again sorry for bothering. (please note that i am a bad programmer and i appoligize if i broke any rules)

```
if object_exists(portal)
{
instance_destroy()
action_create_object(portal,Spr_player.x,Spr_player.y)
}
else
{
action_create_object(portal,Spr_player.x,Spr_player.y)
}
```

Comment: Please post this in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you edit the title a little bit to explain a specific error?

Comment: What version of game maker are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The `instance_destroy()` statement destroys the current `self` instance which is what is executing the code.  You must use the `with (<objectID>) {instance_destroy()}` syntax to destroy another instance.

As long as there is only one instance of `portal` in the room this code should work:

```
if object_exists(portal)
{
with (portal) instance_destroy(); //you should also need a semicolon here to separate
                                  //this statement from the next, it is good practice
                                  //to do this after all statements as I have done.
action_create_object(portal,Spr_player.x,Spr_player.y);
}
else
{
action_create_object(portal,Spr_player.x,Spr_player.y);
}
```

If there are multiple instances of `portal` this will only destroy the first one.  To destroy all you would have to use a `for` loop to iterate through them all.  Off the top of my mind I can not remember the function to get the `id`s of all the instances of an object, but it looks like this is not a problem since each time one is created the existing one is destroyed and thus you will only have one a t a time.

Another way of doing this is just to move the existing portal to the new position.  The only difference here is that the *create event* of the portal will not be executed and any alarms will not be reset.

```
portal.x=Spr_player.x
portal.y=Spr_player.y
```

Again this will only move the first portal if there are more than one.